# How does the metric on a space $X$, affect the way we can define neighborhoods of points $ p \in X$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let's say I have a metric space $X$, and some point $p \in X$. And let say the metric on $X$ is given by

$$d(p, q) = \begin{cases}
1 \ \ \text{(if $p \neq q$)}\\
0\ \ \text{(if $p = q$)}\\
\end{cases}$$

Now does it make sense to define a neighborhood of $p$ with a radius of anything other than $1$? For example can I define a neighborhood of $p$ to be the set of all $q$, where $d(p, q) < \pi$?

e.g is $$N_p = \left\{q : d(p,q) < \pi\right\}$$

a valid neighborhood of a point $p$ in $X$?

I guess what I'm trying to ask, is how does the metric on a space $X$, affect the way we can define neighborhoods of points in $X$.

More generally if I define the metric on $X$ to be $d(p,q) = \lambda$ where $\lambda \in \mathbb{Z}$, does it make sense to define a neighborhood of a point $p \in X$ , with a radius of $\gamma$, where $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: It always makes sense to define any such neighborhood (why would it not?) It just happens that it might only contain one point for example, or all points.

Comment: For your question, yes, they make sense. Furthermore, the metric you defined induces the discrete topology on $X$. You may check this by definition.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, so the way we define neighborhoods of points $p$ in any metric space $X$, is independent of the metric on $X$? I've yet to see this explicitly stated, and it didn't seem all that obvious at first. I was under the assumption that only certain neighborhoods would be valid dependent on the metric.

Comment: @CaveJohnson, What exactly do you mean by '*induces a topology*' I apologize again if this is a trivial question, but the text I'm reading through (Rudin for Analysis), doesn't ever speak of *inducing a topology*

Comment: You may want to read some introductory topology materials before proceeding with Rudin :) They will help you understand the subject better.

Comment: @CaveJohnson, any recommendations? I was hoping to take a look at *Munkres* book on Topology after I completed Rudin

Comment: Hatcher has an [Notes on Introductory Point-Set Topology](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Top/Topdownloads.html) on his web page, which is very convenient to look up before learning topology in detail via Munkres.

Comment: Given a metric space $(X,d)$, it's always a good idea trying to determine the open sets of $X$. They'll be determined by $d$ through neighborhoods (open balls, in fact). Remember that, given $p\in X$ and $r>0$, an open ball $B_r(p) = \{ x\in X : d(x,p) < r \}$ is always an open set. The open sets in $X$ are 'arbitrary unions' and 'finite intersections' of open balls and of others open sets. In this way, the topology induced by $d$ is the family of all the open sets generated by $d$.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, given a point $p\in X$ and a real number $r>0$ you can always define the set $B_r(p)=\{q\in X:d(p,q)<r\}$, and by definition of the metric topology it is always a neighborhood of $p$.  You seem to be merely observing that different values of $r$ might give the same neighborhood: that is, it is possible to have $B_r(p)=B_{r'}(p)$ even if $r\neq r'$.  So if you're just given a neighborhood, it doesn't necessarily have a uniquely defined "radius" (in fact, it also doesn't necessarily have a uniquely defined "center"--in your first example, $B_r(p)=X$ for all $p\in X$ and all $r>1$).

Answer (score 0):

You must keep in mind that a metric is inspired (a generalization of) the Euclidean distance, which is in line with our geometric intuition but that this generalization leads to a function that can be sometimes apparently discrepant of our geometric intuition. For example, in the metric space of p-adic numbers (you can read about this topic in many books if you don't know it), every point of an open ball is the center of the ball.